# Is it advisable for a new PhD student to enroll on a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes

My parents are telling me to do it, but I do expect to pay a lot of money for the first year just because I need to move in and get a lot of things set up (like an ergonomic working environment). So I'm thinking of delaying for a couple of years.

Comment: Re: Waiting a few years. Read this before you decide to wait to start saving - http://bit.ly/wu4KH2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you say you are a student, perhaps you should look carefully at the requirements for contributing to an IRA, whether Traditional or Roth. Unless Congress changed the law recently,
one has to have *earned income* to contribute to an IRA.  So if you were a teaching or
research asssistant receiving W-2 wages while completing your Master's degree, you are
eligible, but if you had a fellowship you are not eligible (unless you had other income,
whether W-2 wages or self-employment income reported on Schedule C).  The amount that
one can contribute is the *smaller* of your earned income and $5000 ($6000 for 50 and older
people).

Comment: Oh wow - thanks very much for the excellent answer! I'm on fellowship for first year, so I guess I'm not eligible then.

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely sure you will need the money in the next year or so I wouldn't do it just because of the hassle.

If you think you might not need to use the money then I would go ahead and fund a Roth IRA for the simple reason that you can get your contributions (NOT earnings on those contributions.) back without paying any penalties if you do end up needing them.

A good summary of the rationale can be found at *My Money Blog's* [Roth IRA Contribution vs. Emergency Fund Savings](http://www.mymoneyblog.com/roth-ira-contribution-vs-emergency-fund-savings.html)